# ng-grid tabbing out of an editable select cell retains previous typeahead value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have a grid that has a select for a editableCellTemplate when I follow these steps:

Steps:

1. Click a Status cell that has a null value
2. Using only the keyboard, type ahead to New by pressing n
3. type ahead to Approved by pressing a
4. tab out of the cell New should have returned to be the value

Is there something I'm missing or is this a bug?

Example: 
[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/aAgd6I?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the select options seems to resolve the issue. This list works in the plunker example:

```
            '<option value="Approved">New</option>' +

            '<option value="Completed">Approved</option>' +

            '<option value="Disregard">Test</option>' +

            '<option value="New">Completed</option>' + 

            '<option value="Test">Disregard</option>' +
```

Still seems like a bug in ng-grid I tested a standalone select outside of the grid and it does not have this behavior.